# How to hide all parents of a child with a repeating data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a dynamic jquery or javascript code, which hides all `<div>` elements, if the `data-event-id=""` is a repeating one on the `<a>` element, so there are no multiple elements with the same attribute, only the first one.

The parents should be invisible like result of CSS `display:none;` but they can also be "deleted" on the code, doesn't really matter.

since my knowledge is limited on css and html, i'm completely lost.

```
<div>
  <a data-event-id="87" href="https://google.com">1</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="48" href="https://google.com">2</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="87" href="https://google.com">3</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="20" href="https://google.com">4</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="48" href="https://google.com">5</a>
</div>
```

On this example, it should only show following links:

1
2
4

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you need, okay , but what have you tried so far where you failed ? You know it is not a coding site.

Answer (score 2):

That's quite simple: you can iterate through your element collection, and check if its `dataset.eventId` is present in a unique set—this can be done by leveraging on [ES6's `Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which stores **unique** values (so it kind of serves as a dictionary). For each iteration, you:

1. check if the `eventId` is in the set. If it is, remove the node
2. store the `eventId` into your unique set for future comparison.

```js
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));
const eventIds = new Set();

elements.forEach(element => {
  const eventId = element.dataset.eventId;
  if (eventIds.has(eventId)) {
    element.parentNode.remove();
  }
  eventIds.add(element.dataset.eventId);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a data-event-id="87" href="https://google.com">1</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="48" href="https://google.com">2</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="87" href="https://google.com">3</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="20" href="https://google.com">4</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="48" href="https://google.com">5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can query for all a-elements and iterate over them. You can keep track of known event-ids with an array where you add newly discovered event-ids. If the id is already in that array, simply hide the parent-element.

```js
let events = [];
$('a').each(function(){
  let event_id = $(this).attr('data-event-id');
  if (!events.includes(event_id)) {
    events.push(event_id);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="87" href="https://google.com">1</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="48" href="https://google.com">2</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="87" href="https://google.com">3</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="20" href="https://google.com">4</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a data-event-id="48" href="https://google.com">5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but unfortunately it doesn't work on my original HTML (nothing happens). I checked it with the simplified HTML and that works. Maybe it's because i've got several `data-event-id=""` in that `<div>` element. Is it possible to select ONLY the parent `<div>`, if it's `class="mec-masonry-item-wrap"`

Maybe that would do the trick.

Comment: In that case you can try it with `$(this).closest( ".mec-masonry-item-wrap" ).hide();` instead of `$(this).parent().hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:not(:first)").remove();`

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  $("[data-event-id$='" + i + "']:not(:first)").remove();
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/metaDesign/ayo0ebp6/10/)

Comment: same as other answer, it is about parent, you need : `var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  $("[data-event-id$='" + i + "']:not(:first)").parent().remove();
}`